# How to make the parent thread wait for the child thread to complete - C#

Tags: c#, multithreading

I am running a background thread to fetch data from the DB so that the current thread(UI) does not freeze. I am using TPL to achieve this.

```
List<string> _myList1, _myList2;
private void LoadCollections(){
    Task db_task = new Task(() => CallDB());
    var continuations = db_task.ContinueWith((ant) =>
    {
        _myList1 = GetDataFromMetaData1();
        _myList2 = GetDataFromMetaData2();
    });

    db_task.Start();
    LoadTemplates(); //execute only after 'db_task' completes execution
}
```

In the above code

`CallDB()` - Fetches the data from the database and stores it in a metadata. In this case, consider it a list of strings. (say `List<string> MetaStrings`)

`GetDataFromMetaData1()` and `GetDataFromMetaData2()` - Fetches 2 separate lists which are sub-lists of `MetaStrings`.

Now I wish to execute the function `LoadTemplates` only after `_myList1` and `_myList2` are loaded, i.e., when `db_task` has completed execution. Currently, I am using this

```
while(_mylist1==null && _mylist2==null)
    Thread.Sleep(50);

LoadTemplates();
```

But this obviously freezes the UI as the UI thread goes to sleep. So can anyone suggest an efficient way to handle the scenario?

PS: `LoadTemplates()` initializes some `ObservableCollection` variables. If `LoadTemplates()` is called inside the child thread, `db_task` then the following error is thrown `This type of CollectionView does not support changes to its SourceCollection from a thread different from the Dispatcher thread`. Hence arises the scenario of thread-waiting.

Comment: cant you use async & await?

Comment: Actually the function `LoadCollections` is a messenger event. In other words, the ViewModel registers to call `LoadCollections` when a user clicks a button on the UI. So I am a little lost how to use async/await in this case.

Comment: can't you use Task.WaitAll(tasks);

Comment: Can you not use `await Task.Run()`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're asking the wrong question. When running a process on a secondary thread, you never want the primary thread to *wait* for the operation to complete. That's just a waste…you might as well have just run the operation on the primary thread and been done with it.

So instead, the question is: how do I make the primary (parent) thread handle the completion of the secondary (child) thread?

Based on the error message you get, it seems you are writing this using WPF. Which means one answer to the question you *should* have asked is that you call Dispatcher.Invoke from an event handler that responds to the completion of your secondary thread.

As suggested by Terry, it's possible you can use the async/await feature. For example, this *might* work (hard to say without a full code example):

```
List<string> _myList1, _myList2;
private async void LoadCollections(){
    Task db_task = new Task(() => CallDB());

    var continuations = db_task.ContinueWith((ant) =>
    {
        _myList1 = GetDataFromMetaData1();
        _myList2 = GetDataFromMetaData2();
    });

    db_task.Start();

    await continuations;

    LoadTemplates(); //execute only after 'db_task' completes execution
}
```

In other words, go ahead and schedule your tasks as you're doing now, but use async and await to set things up so that LoadTemplates() is called only after the continuation has completed (which in turn won't be executed until the initial DB task has completed), and in particular, such that LoadTemplates() is executed in the main Dispatcher thread where LoadCollections is called in the first place.

Note that ideally, the return type of LoadCollections would actually be Task. The compiler likes this better and it would allow you better handling of exceptions that might come up. But void should be fine, and is not uncommon when dealing with event handler methods.

EDIT: I also meant to mention, an alternative that involves change the code more drastically but which IMHO is more in keeping with the async/await pattern would be either to simply await the original db_task and then do the "continuations" statements inline (i.e. not in a task), or (if those statements are themselves long-running and should be executed in the background) to still await the original task and then also await the continuations as their own task instead explicitly as a continuation of the DB task.

For example (assuming that the continuation operations are brief and can be run on the main thread):

```
List<string> _myList1, _myList2;
private async void LoadCollections(){
    await Task.Run(() => CallDB());

    _myList1 = GetDataFromMetaData1();
    _myList2 = GetDataFromMetaData2();

    LoadTemplates(); //execute only after 'db_task' completes execution
}
```

Comment: I was trying to solve using `Dispatcher.Invoke` as u had mentioned, `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(LoadTemplates, DispatcherPriority.ContextIdle);`. But this does not seem to work. Do u know how to make the `Dispatcher.Invoke` respond to the completion of a secondary thread.

Comment: First, define "does not seem to work". That could be a lot of different things. Second, why use ContextIdle for the priority? I mean, that should work but how about starting with Normal and then go from there. Third, while using the Dispatcher should work, async/await is IMHO simpler and produces clearer code. Did you try it that way instead?

Comment: The solution runs. Thanks!! Not that it matters, but I get a warning message: `Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.` Do u know what it means!!

Comment: @user1603970: glad to hear it's working now. As far as the warning goes, it means what it says: normally in an async method, one would use `await` when executing a statement that returns a Task or Task<T>, but you have one where you don't use `await`. Because you don't use `await`, instead of returning at that point as the method would do were it written conventionally, it will keep executing (until, of course, it does reach an `await` expression).

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you question correctly CallDB() must be run first, then the GetDataFromMetaData functions can run, and then finally LoadTemplates. I would use ansy await as follows:

```
    private async void LoadCollections()
    {

        await Task.Run(() => CallDB());

        Task[] tasks = new Task[1]
        {
            _myList1 = GetDataFromMetaData1(),
            _myList2 = GetDataFromMetaData2()
        };

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks); 

        LoadTemplates(); //execute only after 'db_task' completes execution

    }
```